# when i click the open button a text box should appear in the page

Tags: javascript, html, css

when i click the active button a box should appear in the page , and when i click closed it should hide from page

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-secondary ">
        <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" autocomplete="off" checked> Open
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-secondary">
        <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" autocomplete="off"> Closed
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: where the JavaScript code ? and where the DIV you want to show and hide ?

Comment: That's not how you use `data-toggle` either; consider not using that here, or just use one button to toggle the textbox. If the box is opened once, you wouldn't expect it to be opened again, would you?

Comment: The question looks more like a teacher giving a homework to their pupil . If you need help then show what have you tried first and what's not working as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is that what you want ?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[name=options]').change(function(e) {
    var isOpen = $(this).val() == "Open";

    $('#box').toggle(isOpen);
  });
});
```

```css
#box {
  padding-top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
<label class="btn btn-secondary ">
    <input type="radio" name="options" value="Open" id="option1" autocomplete="off" checked> Open
</label>
<label class="btn btn-secondary">
    <input type="radio" name="options" value="Closed" id="option2" autocomplete="off"> Closed
</label>
</div>

<div id="box">More Info</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use change event of radio button

```js
$("input[name='options']").on('change',function(){
    if($(this).attr('id') == 'option1'){ 
        $('#myDiv').show();
    }else{
        $('#myDiv').hide();
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="height:100px" id="myDiv">MY DIV WILL BE HERE</div>
            <body>
<div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
                <label class="btn btn-secondary ">
                    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" autocomplete="off" checked> Open
                </label>
                <label class="btn btn-secondary">
                    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" autocomplete="off"> Closed
                </label>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a bootstrap modal and modal button to open a box on a button click. if you want to make a custom button then here is the code for in jquery.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
$("button.active").on("click",function()
{
$(".page-box").toggle();
//page-box is the box container which you want to open 
})


});
```